# async validator (AsyncValidatorFn) is never subscribed to

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular2-form-validation

I wrote a custom Form Validator but in `errors` it just has `"_isScalar": false, "source": {    "_isScalar": false, "source": { "_isScalar": false, "source": {"_isScalar": false},      "operator": {}}, "operator": {"total": 1}` and the form is never valid.

This is my Validator:

```
export function asyncEmailValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return of(control.value).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res && res.indexOf('example.de') < -1 ? { eMailUnavailable: true } : null;
      }),
      take(1), finalize(() => {})
    );
  };
}
```

This is how i use it:

```
emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.email,
  asyncEmailValidator()
]);
```

From debugging i found that the map Block where i check for example.de is never reached and i fail to understand why. The function itself is used and output before the inner return is shown.

I saw this structure in multiple examples online but it just doesn't seem to work for me.

I am using `@angular/forms` `10.0.14`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asynchronous validators should be specified as a third argument as follows:

```
 new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email], [asyncEmailValidator()]);
```